# Selecting input hidden value inside Div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select the `hidden` input value inside the last `Div` but it returns `undefined` value, I tried all the possible solutions available but nothing works for me properly. I know I am missing something.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 video_main_category" id="appendData">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage" id="itemList">
        <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="7">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 HomePage" id="itemList">
        <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage" id="itemList">
        <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="3">
        <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="5">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage" id="itemList">
        <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="4">
        <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is My JS

```
function appendData() {
    var MainLastID = $('#appendData').children('#itemList input:hidden[name=CatShowID]').last().val();
    alert(MainLastID);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the last hidden or all hidden inputs?

Comment: @Eddie I just need the last hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#appendData input:hidden[name=CatShowID]`

Note: `id`s should be unique, you can use `itemList` as a class.

```js
var MainLastID = $('#appendData input:hidden[name=CatShowID]').last().val();

console.log(MainLastID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 video_main_category" id="appendData">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage itemList">
    <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="7">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 HomePage itemList">
    <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage itemList">
    <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-12 DataHomePage itemList">
    <input name="CatShowID" type="hidden" value="4">
    <input name="ItemShowID" type="hidden" value="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 $('#appendData > #itemList input:hidden[name=CatShowID]').last()
```

Instead of this:

```
$('#appendData').children('#itemList input:hidden[name=CatShowID]').last()
```

Your problem is that you have too much in the children selector (.children will only match direct descendants)

Comment: Thanks but its returning in the object can I use `.val();` after `.last()` function to get only value?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Also see Eddie's answer about how ids should be unique.  Use class for itemList for best practice

Answer (score 0):

You can this in many solution to solve this, Here is my solution

```
$('#appendData').children(":last-child").find('input[name="CatShowID"]').val();
```